# WCF Data Service for Azure Table Storage

Tags: wcf, azure-table-storage

I want to using WCF Data Service (OData) for Azure Table Storage. Is that possible to used for Table Storage first, if Yes. So Please tell me the steps that required to perform.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the WCF RIA services Toolkit April 2011 may be able to solve your problem.  Can read a little about it here: http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2011/04/13/MIX11Releases.aspx  theres a link to download the toolkit from MSDN.

It allows you to create a Domain Service using a table storage data context.  I've tried it out for Rest to use Table storage in Silverlight, it should allow you to expose it as OData.

Here's a vid about using WCF RIA services to expose other endpoints like jSON and OData.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/05/14/silverlight-tv-episode-26-exposing-soap-json-and-odata-endpoints-from-ria-services.aspx